# Twitter Bootstrap - Span Columns not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get started with Twitter Bootstrap, but for some reason, anything I do, results in a div spanning the entire page. As such, I cannot get the grid system / navigation bar to look right as every div appears to have it's own line.

I am sure that this is a simple fix but I am completely baffled.

http://jsfiddle.net/Aq5xn/show/

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            @section('title')
                Page Title
            @show
        </title>
        {{-- Ensures proper rendering & touch zooming --}}
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        {{-- HTML::style('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css') --}}
        {{ HTML::style('/css/bootstrap.css') }}
        {{ HTML::style('/css/style.css') }}
    </head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">  
      <div class="navbar-inner">  
        <div class="container-fluid">  
          <a class="brand" href="#">asdf</a>  
          <div class="nav-collapse">  
            <ul class="nav">  
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>  
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>  
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>  
            </ul>  
            <p class="navbar-text pull-right">Logged in as <a href="#">username</a></p>  
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->  
        </div>  
      </div>  
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">  
            <div class="span4">{{-- @yield('content') --}}</div>  
            <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
            <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{-- Scripts are placed here --}}
    {{ HTML::script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}

    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Bootstrap not working]

Comment: also in addition to the answers below, you've spelt fluid wrong in the container class.

Comment: and you are assumingly calling two version of bootstrap in your CSS, remove either the local copy or the CDN version. Check as well you aren't using bootstrap 2.3.2 locally and also calling 3.0 - that will make things messy very quickly.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough {{-- --}} is a blade templating comment. As such, I am not calling 2 versions.

Comment: well spotted on the typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing `Bootstrap 2.3.2` with `Bootstrap 3.0.0`. you can find the differences outlined in the [CHANGELOG](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration) concerning the migration details. Glancing at your code, i see that `navbar-inner` class has been removed, `container-fluid` has been replaced by `container`, same for `row-fluid` and so on.

Basically, you're using Bootstrap 2.3.2 code with the new Bootstrap 3.0.0 engine... without migration. Follow the instructions outlined in the above link to know what you need to change and how.

PS: As of version `3.1` you can still use `.container-fluid`, you just need to use `.row` classes as with standard containers. Probably this was still the case even with version `3.0`, I may have misunderstood the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, the new release came out just after I learned a good level of bootstrap and now I'll have to learn it back again ^^" @Gravy Anyway bootstrap is so straightforward that you don't really need tutorials, just pick the components you need and place them in your page. You'll learn better and faster that way :D

Answer (score 4):

Please do note that you are using Bootstrap 3.0.0.

span class is no longer in use. Changed to .col-md-* , read the details at the link below.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

if you still wish to use span class. Please revert it back to Bootstrap 2.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

try this in bootstrap 3 http://getbootstrap.com:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse shadow main-menu" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">asdf</a>
    </div>
<div style="height: auto;" class="navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </nav>
```